# Android GoogleMaps v2 Drag and Drop to map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, events, drag-and-drop

As title states, I'm doing an Android GoogleMapsv2 app.  The user will be dragging onto the map with a custom drop-shadow image.

I need to capture the lat/lon of the ACTION_DRAG_ENDED event.  I found some guides that discuss adding a SupportMapFragment over the map, but they only support responding to a onMouseClicked event on the map.  Since my event is driven by the end of a *drag* event, this is less than helpful.

I considered having my custom drop-shadow linger and having the user simply click on the drop shadow to trigger the map event, but I think it sucks to force them to take another action and I'm unclear on how I'd keep the drop-shadow from vanishing on release anyway.

Any suggestions?  Is the approach fundamentally flawed or is there a way to navigate the GoogleMap and Android Drag and Drop APIs to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what are you dragging on maps ... But according to Google's official documentation shadows were removed in version 3.14 of the Google Maps API. Any shadows specified programmatically will be ignored.

Please refer to the following [link.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons)

Comment: This is for Android.  As far as I know, that means API v2.  That's an important thing to distinguish.  I am dragging an Android view that the map is completely unaware exists.  What I'm trying to accomplish is capturing the user's touch at the position where they release the drag, then converting that position to the Geo lat/long on the map at those view coordinates.